# source code won't run in python 2.7.10

Tags: python

I'm a python newbie and have come across the following with content in chapter 10:

When I run the code in python 2.7.10 it gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dave\learnpython\py3e_source\chapter10\click_counter.py", line 32, in <module>
app = Application(root)
File "C:\Users\Dave\learnpython\py3e_source\chapter10\click_counter.py", line 10, in __init__
super(Application, self).__init__(master)
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

The book was written on the understanding python 3> would be used. But is there anything I can do to resolve this in 2.7.10? I 'm at a loss as to what to do.

Original code, except for 'from tkinter' being changed to 'from Tkinter':

```
# Click Counter
# Demonstrates binding an event with an event handler

from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    """ GUI application which counts button clicks. """ 
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize the frame. """
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)  
        self.grid()
        self.bttn_clicks = 0    # the number of button clicks
        self.create_widget()

    def create_widget(self):
        """ Create button which displays number of clicks. """
        self.bttn = Button(self)
        self.bttn["text"]= "Total Clicks: 0"
        self.bttn["command"] = self.update_count
        self.bttn.grid()

    def update_count(self):
        """ Increase click count and display new total. """
        self.bttn_clicks += 1
        self.bttn["text"] = "Total Clicks: " + str(self.bttn_clicks)

# main
root = Tk()
root.title("Click Counter")
root.geometry("200x50")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can I see the source code?

Comment: Added at bottom of original post Kevin.

Comment: Thanks, now we can check what's wrong :)

Comment: "The book was written on the understanding python 3> would be used." - install Python 3, simple as that! Why do you waste your time learning a language that's reached its end of lifetime?

Comment: Originally I was using 3, but when I picked up ' Learn Python the hard way'  I was encouraged to use 2 (basic premise of the guy's argument was that it was still more relevant if I remember).

Answer (score 2):

I've not used Tk in any projects, but I suspect that Frame is not created using new-style classes, and `super()` is only available for new-style (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).  Try changing your `__init__` method to be this:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    """ Initialize the frame. """
    Frame.__init__(self, master)   # <-- CHANGED  
    self.grid()
    self.bttn_clicks = 0
    self.create_widget()
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank's alot. Now I get can get back on the learning grind :) Thanks for the help everyone. Dave

Comment: You are correct: tkinter classes are old style classes.